Ответ на инлайн-кнопки. Как ответить пользователю после нажатия на кнопку сообщением с текстом нажатой кнопки?
Я прописала 3 сообщения с кнопками, пользователь должен выбрать некоторые кнопки (условия прописаны в тексте кнопки), после чего по задумке должно высвечиваться сообщение, в котором написано что-то вроде: "вы прошли анкетирование, вот ваши ответы: {текст кнопок через запятую, которые выбирал пользователь}"
bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])def start(message, markup=None):
mess = f'Hello, my dear friend, {message.from_user.first_name}'
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')
msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                       'Hi, сейчас ты должен ответить на несколько несложных вопросов от этого бота',
                       reply_markup=markup)
nomber = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='1', callback_data='1')
two = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='2', callback_data='2')
three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='3', callback_data='3')
five = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='5', callback_data='5')
nomber.add(one, two, three, five)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери сколько слов ты хочешь изучать (возможен выбор только одного ответа)', reply_markup=nomber)

mess = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
travel = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='travel', callback_data='travel')
person = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='person', callback_data='person')
home = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='home', callback_data='home')
city = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='city', callback_data='city')
school = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='school', callback_data='school')
nature = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='nature', callback_data='nature')
mess.add(travel, person, home, city, school, nature)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери интересующие тебя темы (возможен выбор нескольких ответов)', reply_markup=mess)

markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
A1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(new.A1.name, callback_data='A1')
A2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(new.A2.name, callback_data='A2')
B1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(new.B1.name, callback_data='B1')
B2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(new.B2.name, callback_data='B2')
C1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(new.C1.name, callback_data='C1')
C2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(new.C2.name, callback_data='C2')
markup.add(A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери уровень языка, на котором ты сейчас находишься (возможен выбор только одного ответа)', reply_markup=markup)

